# Integral with e and log

Tags: integration, gaussian-integral

so I have the following integral $$\int_0^\infty e^{-\log^2x}dx$$  I tried the following substitution $\log x=t \, ; \log^2x =t^2$ and substituted got to $$\int_0^\infty e^{-t^2}e^{-t}dt$$ should I split this integral and use Gauss integral?or what method should I approach I get blocked after substituting.

Comment: finish the square. then use gaussian integral  look here  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral

Comment: @Isham: the procedure you refer to is called "completing the square" in English.

Comment: @fabian thank you ....

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the first step seems wrong. If $x=e^t \iff t = \ln x$ then
$$
I = \int_0^\infty e^{-\ln^2 x}dx = \int_{t=-\infty}^{t=\infty}e^{-t^2}e^{-t}dt
$$
and we can complete the square in the exponent, noting that
$$
-t^2-t = 1/4-(t+1/2)^2
$$
and hence (using $u=t+1/2$)
$$
I = e^{1/4} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(t+1/2)^2}dt
  = e^{1/4} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-u^2}du
  = e^{1/4} \sqrt{\pi}
  = \sqrt[4]{\pi^2e}
$$
using the usual trick with polar coordinates.

Comment: @Isham thanks, fixing -- no change really :)

Comment: @Isham thanks again, hope it's right this time :)